# Is it possible to handle Firebase messages in native Kotlin in a Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm writing an app where I need to start up some native background processes when a data notification comes in.

With the current Flutter plugin for Firebase, the native Kotlin or Java implementation has stopped working. Is there a way to receive these notifications in the Application.kt, so that the FlutterEngine doesn't need to be started when the app is terminated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for an answer to this same issue, I managed to get it working by implementing a custom messagingReceiver.

In the manifest, add these lines:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And then create a `MyFirebaseMessagingReceiver` class:

```
class MyFirebaseMessagingReceiver: FlutterFirebaseMessagingReceiver() {

    val TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingReceiver"

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message received")

        intent?.extras.let {
            val remoteMessage= RemoteMessage(it)
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data: ${remoteMessage.data}")
        }

        super.onReceive(context, intent)
    }
}
```